# Angular 2 reference class member from within audio nativelement event method

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have the following class and I am trying to reference the selectedSong object from within the onplay event of the native element.  Is there a way to do this?  In Angular 1.x you could use $scope... etc..

```
export class PlayerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('myAudio') myAudio: any;

selectedSong: Song;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let audio = this.myAudio.nativeElement;
    audio.onended = function () {
        console.log("song ended");
        //get handle to selected song NOT working as "this" refers to the audio object
        let s = this.selectedSong;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's caused by `function`. Use arrow functions instead:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let audio = this.myAudio.nativeElement;
    audio.onended = () => {
        console.log("song ended");
        //get handle to selected song NOT working as "this" refers to the audio object
        let s = this.selectedSong;
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions